# 'jpeg' function in R not saving current device

Tags: r, plot, jpeg

I am trying to use the jpeg function in R to save graphics automatically. The function works perfectly if I just use the default graphics device and do not try to alter it. But when I try and alter the device by the 'X11' function it does not work (I think it is recording the null device and not the X11 device).Below is some code you can run your self. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    x<-rnorm(10, 3, 4)

    y<-rnorm(10, 68, 2)

    jpeg(file="YOUR FILE PATH", quality=100)

     X11(width=20, height=15)

     par(mfrow=c(2,2))

     plot(x,y, main="1")
     plot(x,y,main="2")
     plot(x,y, main="3")
     plot(x,y,main="4")

     dev.off()
```

Answer (score 10):

`jpeg` and `X11` are in some sense competing devices.  You can only output to one thing at a time.  So when you call `X11` after `jpeg`, you are telling R to send all output to the X11 device.  Take out `X11` and pass your height and width arguments directly to `jpeg`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have done that and now I am getting an error:

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have done that and now I am getting an error: "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large". I understand R is trying to tell me the specified dimensions are not suitable so I tested the same width and length using X11 function and the plots worked perfectly. I don't understand this error as the dimensions I have supplied seem reasonable

Comment: Note that for the graphics devices `bmp`, `jpeg`, `tiff` and `png` by default the width and height values are in pixels not inches.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the effect of calling `X11` will be. You could set the width and height directly:

```
jpeg('filename', width=20, height=30, units='cm', res=100)
```

Comment: `x11()` will open a new device that becomes the current device. Plotting will now be done on that device, and the trailing `dev.off()` will close that `x11()` device. Hence the `jpeg()` one is still open and doesn't have any plotting on it anyway.